# Как сохранить изменения в БД? sql command, c#, VS

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, visual-studio

Проблема решена! Ответ: При запуске с папки bin введенные данные сохраняются!
Вот так ввожу изменения:

```
 string connStr = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\LitMapPoltavaData.mdf;Integrated Security=True";
 SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
 try
 {

     //пробуем подключится
     conn.Open();
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
     cmd.Parameters.Clear();
     cmd.Connection = conn;
     cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE Writers SET Id = @Id, Surname = @Surname, Name = @Name, Lived = @Lived, Birthplace = @Birthplace, ShortInfo = @ShortInfo WHERE Id = @Id";
     //Добавить параметры
     ...
     //Выполнить
     int recordsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

     if (recordsAffected == 0)
     {
         cmd.CommandText = "Insert Into Writers (Id, Surname, Name, Lived, Birthplace, ShortInfo)" +
                           "Values(@Id, @Surname, @Name, @Lived, @Birthplace, @ShortInfo)";
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
 }
 finally
 {
     conn.Close();
     conn.Dispose();
 }
```

Данные в базу вводятся и выводятся после нормально. Нужно чтоб после закрытия и нового открытия приложения данные в БД оставались!

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос, а почему они должны стираться?

Comment: commit - это больше к SVN

Comment: _"Нужно чтоб ... данные в БД оставались"_ А у вас они не остаются? По коду вроде всё более-менее. Транзакцию вы не открываете, соответственно сommit произойдёт на уровне отдельных statement, т.е. специально делать Commit здесь не надо.

Comment: update вносит изменения в базу сразу же (вы же не используете явное управление транзакциями). скорее всего вы просто перезапускаете приложение из-под студии, по F5, и она заново копирует пустой LitMapPoltavaData.mdf в bin\LitMapPoltavaData.mdf, перетирая изменения. попробуйте запускать приложение прямо из bin.

Comment: @PashaPash, в Oracle без явного commit, commit не происходит.

Comment: Просто воспользуйтесь EntityFramework Code First

Comment: @Vyacheslav, какая у вас СУБД?

Comment: @pegoopik - судя по классам и строке соединения - SQL Server

Comment: @МстиславПавлов дело в том, что данные у топикастера в базу сохраняются, и теряются при перезапуске приложения. скорее всего билд перетирает файл базы данных. вы уверены что Code First возьмет и решит эту проблему? :)

Comment: @PashaPash вы оказались правы, спасибо!

Comment: @PashaPash я просто вижу по коду, что человек явно изучает работу с sql, по этому я ему и порекомендовал EF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE в SQL Server вносит изменения в базу сразу же (вы же не используете явное управление транзакциями).

Cкорее всего вы просто перезапускаете приложение из-под студии, по F5, и она заново копирует пустой LitMapPoltavaData.mdf в bin\LitMapPoltavaData.mdf, перетирая изменения.

Попробуйте запускать приложение прямо из bin.